# Loop through files created in certain time frame and get the file names

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, directoryinfo

I need to access files in a folder which were created in the past 10 hours and identify the file names. Please advise what I am doing wrong as I am not getting any output.

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\ServerName\SharedFolder\");
var files = directory.GetFiles()
            .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    string filename = file.Name.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(filename);
}
```

Comment: Well could you inspect your `files` variable and check, if you have indeed the files you expect to be in there?

Comment: Try removing Where condition and check whether all files which are in directory are coming, and also whether LastWriteTime is coming correctly while you debugging

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is the path correct and do you have access to the path?

Comment: It works with a local folder. Have you checked the validity and the access rights to the folder path?

Comment: Ok thanks all let me check all sugestions

Comment: Have you tried to create some new files in the folder and then run the code? have you tried to run the code without filtering the directory files list?

Comment: Thanks all at the end it was a problem with the network file path, if I change the file path to local it works fine.  Thank you all for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code  is good , but if you put some validation like code below then it will be good code.

```
   DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10);
            DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\ServerName\SharedFolder\");
            var files = directory.GetFiles("*.*")  //add this.--
                        .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= fromDate && file.LastWriteTime <= toDate);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // add this.
                if (file.Name != "Thumbs.db" && file.Name.StartsWith("~$") == false && file.Name.ToLower().Contains(".xml") == false)
                {
                    string filename = file.Name.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(filename);
                }
            }
```

hope you like it.